# how to generate different samples using PixelCNN?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying pixelcnn, which is auto-regressive generative model. After training, the model receive an all-zero tensor and generate the next pixel form the left top coner. Now that the model parameters are fixed, does the model only can produce the same outputs starting from the same zero tensor? How to produce different samples?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you always provide an all-zero tensor. However, for PixelCNN each pixel location is represented by a distribution. So when you do the forward pass you then sample from a random distribution at the end. That is how the pixel values are different each run.

This is of course because PixelCNN is a probabilistic neural network. So the pixels, as mentioned before, are all represented by conditional probability distributions of all the layers below, not just point estimates.

Comment: I see. You mean that after one iteration the network produces a distribution for one pixel, then we can sample a pixel value from that distrubition. So the output can vary. I see. Thanks. I thought that the argmax one is always picked.

Comment: I did it. It is multinomial distribution. Thanks.